# unable to retrieve image from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

i am trying to retrieve image that i manually uploaded in the firebase into an imageview but cant retrieve, i gave internet permission, checked rules, neither identify anything in logcat. the code is:

```
public class homepage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private static final int IMAGE_CODE=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.g_image);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
}
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==IMAGE_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Products");
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    Picasso.with(homepage.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(mImage);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: no error, but image doesnt pops up , nothing happens

Comment: is it getting stored in firebase storage?

Comment: i manually uploaded it in the database, in a folder named "Products"

Comment: i already did it, in the storage section, from the firebase dashboard, i created a folder and uploaded an image, now i want to retrieve that image, that simple and above is the code. but it doesnt works

Comment: in addition to that, i do not want to upload it first and then retrieve it. i uploaded it manually and now i want to retrieve it. i hope i am able to make you understand

Comment: when you write `putFile()` it is uploading it again, even if you uploaded it manually before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169308/discussion-between-anish-arya-and-peter-haddad).

Comment: lets continue in chatroom

Comment: @PeterHaddad bro, i need your help

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I've created two activities; one is creating account (using createuserwithemailandpassword() method) and the next is creating profile which takes input like name,company name, contact number... which i stored in "Profile_Details" as a child in database. Now i want that whenever the user logins  with their account, his name is displayed above (like "Welcome Anish"). How can i do that? Just Curious...Should I ask this as a seperate question?

Comment: You just need to retrieve the data from the database.. But yes its better to ask it as a separate question

Comment: @PeterHaddad ok, I'll Try. Can we talk tommorow? It's Past Midnight and i need some sleep, also i have lots of questions to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
StorageReference storageref= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(); 
pathReference=storageref.child("Products/images.png"); 
pathReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() { 
  @Override 
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) { 
        //got the url
     } 
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
  @Override
 public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle any errors
  } 
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url